# Unity Remote screen resolution

Tags: unity, android, resolution

I just made a game using Unity. However, when I tested the game on unity remote, the resolution or graphic of the game was really low compared to the actual game. Would this change when I deploy the game or do I have to tweak the settings? If I have to tweak the setting, can you guys tell me what to tweak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According [this answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1094009/view.html) from Unity Answers Forum, Unity Remote doesn't really play game on device, rather than it stream video output to device from editor.

The final presentation of Your game will be different than what You get in editor/Unity Remote.

Additionaly You can always check how will Your game will presents under different resoultions while developing, just by switching resolutions in game view.

[image: Resolution changing]

IMHO, it's always best to test on few real devices with game installed from apk file when targeting for Android.

Comment: Just to add to this answer. You should only use unity remote to test Touch and Input specific code that cant be tested on a PC. Never EVER use unity remote to try and see how your game will look or perform on the device. Think of the remote as using your mobile device as another input device.